# update source code of react through azure pipeline

Tags: reactjs, powershell, azure-devops

I have created a react environment variable in .env file and is able to update it through command prompt or power shell now my aim is to update it through azure pipeline so add a powershell script.But I am not able to figure out how to read or write data in .env file through a azure pipeline powershell script. I wish to change base url for differnet envirnoments dev stage prod (base_url_dev = https://projectName.dev.azurewebsites.net/). Please let me know If there is any other way

Answer (score 1):

You would commit your file like this:
`base_url = '#{base_url}#'` (never commit enivornment specific values into Source Code)

And then set a `base_url` variable in each AzDo Stage to the actual value. (You can also use stage scoped variable groups)

in each stage, use a `replacetokens` step and target your `.env` file to replace the `#{base_url}#` to the actual value you declared for each stage.

Answer (score 1):

> update source code of react through azure pipeline

We could remove the `base url` from the `.env` file, then use a Inline powershell task to set the `base url` via [Logging Command](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md)：

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=REACT_BASE_URL;]$(REACT_BASE_URL)"
```

Then define the variable `REACT_BASE_URL` with different value for different stages in the **Variables** tab:

[image]

**Alternatively**, just like michiel said, we could use the task [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) to update the value in the `.env` file.

Change the base_url`s values to` #{REACT_BASE_URL}#`：

```
REACT_BASE_URL = #{REACT_BASE_URL}#
```

Then, also defined the variable `REACT_BASE_URL` with different value for different stages in the Variables tab.

And add the task Replace Tokens in the pipeline:

[image]